# How should scheduling be handled in a bare-metal multi-core environment?

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi3, bare-metal

I am currently preparing to write my own simple OS for a raspberry PI 3. My current biggest issue is process scheduling, namely how, where, and when I should run the scheduler.

I have an old book about OS design that covers preemptive scheduling in some detail, but it is written for the 8088 and so it never deals with more than one core.

Would it be better to schedule each core independently or should I have one master scheduler that handles all the cores? How do I manage access to the process list(s)? How do I manage the case where the scheduler is running and a process on a different core needs to be rescheduled?

Can anyone recommend some good (preferably free) books or other (downloadable) resources on OS design that aren't outdated and/or pure theory?

Comment: have you finished one for a single core yet?  I would start with one core, leave the others spinning in their infinite loops.  Then worry about multi-core.  No doubt there are tons of online resources and/or textbooks on the topic once you are ready.

Comment: I would really rather go directly to multi-core. I do have good resources for single core scheduling, but from what I have read they do not scale to multicore well or at all.